# How to use strtok in text file

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, token, strtok

I have a text file that looks like this :

```
Jane Smith 1111

Alex John 2222

Joe Bon 1234
```

I'm trying to parse this data and put it into an array of structs. When I get a line from the file and use strtok, the right data is printed but it's not copied into the struct. How can I copy the data? Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUM 100

struct object {
  char fname[20];
  char lname[20];
  char phoneNum[20];
};

typedef struct object Person;

int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  FILE *fp;
  int i = 0;
  Person person[MAX_NUM];

  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  char *token;

  char line[256];

  int y = 1;

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    token = strtok(line, " ");
    arr[0] = token;

     while(token != NULL) {
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
      arr[y] = token;
      y++;
    }
    strcpy(person[i].fname, arr[0]);
    strcpy(person[i].lname, arr[1]);
    strcpy(person[i].phoneNum, arr[2]);
    i++;
  }

  printf("%s\n", person[i].fname); //why does nothing print
  printf("%s\n", person[i].lname);
  printf("%s\n", person[i].phoneNum);

}
```

Comment: What is the value of `y` after the second line is read? This might be a good moment to learn how to use a debugger, but you should be able to answer my question using a piece of paper to simulate the computer.

Comment: The hunt for the mysterious origins of `arr` is left as a challenge for us ?

Comment: One possible take-away here: it is always tempting to blame bugs on the most mysterious (to you) part of the program. So when you are learning a new API, your tendency will be to assume the problem is related to that. Sherlock Holmes would not make that mistake. He would tell you that most errors are stupid little typos, which all of us make from time to time, and your best strategy to find the problem is to objectively view the actual evidence without prejudgements. It 's tgat habit which makes Holmes a better detective than Cpl. Plod.

Comment: I highly recommend NOT using strtok (which according to Brian Kernighan is the "worst designed function in computing history"). Get an implementation of strsep and save yourself the headache.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUM 100

struct object {
  char fname[20];
  char lname[20];
  char phoneNum[20];
};

typedef struct object Person;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    Person person[MAX_NUM];
    char line[256];

    // Check command line arguments
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    // Check FILE *
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("FAILED TO OPEN %s\n", argv[1]);
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
    {
        if (sscanf(line, "%s %s %s", person[i].fname, person[i].lname, person[i].phoneNum) < 3)
        {
            printf("ILLEGAL TEXT: <<%s>>\n", line);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("RECORD %s %s %s\n", person[i].fname, person[i].lname, person[i].phoneNum);
            i++;
        }
    }

    // Close file
    fclose(fp);

    printf("%d RECORD(S) HAVE(HAS) BEEN PARSED SUCCESSFULLY\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

demo.data:

```
Jane Smith 1111 
Alex John 2222 
Joe Bon 1234 
Invalid line
 Space  Tab 6666
Joy Allen 2333
Jane Smith 1111 
Alex John 2222 
Joe Bon 1234 
Invalid line
 Space Tab 6666
Joy Allen 2333
Jane Smith 1111 
Alex John 2222 
Joe Bon 1234 
Invalid line
 Space Tab 6666
Joy Allen 2333
```

Run:

```
$ ./demo demo.data
RECORD Jane Smith 1111
RECORD Alex John 2222
RECORD Joe Bon 1234
ILLEGAL TEXT: <<Invalid line
>>
RECORD Space Tab 6666
RECORD Joy Allen 2333
RECORD Jane Smith 1111
RECORD Alex John 2222
RECORD Joe Bon 1234
ILLEGAL TEXT: <<Invalid line
>>
RECORD Space Tab 6666
RECORD Joy Allen 2333
RECORD Jane Smith 1111
RECORD Alex John 2222
RECORD Joe Bon 1234
ILLEGAL TEXT: <<Invalid line
>>
RECORD Space Tab 6666
RECORD Joy Allen 2333
15 RECORD(S) HAVE(HAS) BEEN PARSED SUCCESSFULLY
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should wonder what can be the value of `i` at the time of printing...

It is where you have left it, just one passed the last value stored in the `person` array, so it is no surprise that you get no value.

The fix is trivial: just loop **up to `i`**:

```
  for(y=0; y<i; y++) {
    printf("%s\n", person[y].fname);
    printf("%s\n", person[y].lname);
    printf("%s\n", person[y].phoneNum);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse this data and put it into an array of struct you can use this function:

```
char  ** split(char string[], int * num, char * sep) 
{
    char * pch;
    char ** out = 0;
    int i = 0;
    pch = strtok(string, sep);

    while (pch != 0) {
        out = realloc(out, (i + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        out[i] = malloc(strlen(pch) + 1);
        strcpy(out[i], pch);
        ++i;
        pch = strtok(NULL, sep);
    }
    *num = i;
    return out;
}
```

The function splits the string into 2d arrays that you can put in to the struct